# undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds_abort'

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, linker-errors

while compiling the code with compiler flag `-fsanitize=bounds` for clang-4.0 , i seem to be getting this linking error although there is no out of bound access that the code is doing.
Any help here when does the compiler throw this error - undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds_abort`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to add `-fsanitize=bounds` to your linker flags.

Comment: its added in linker flags but still :(

Comment: @gabbar what if you use `-fsanitize=undefined` in `LDFLAGS`?